# Flutter App UI bigger on real device than in simulator

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, flutter-renderflex-error

I have this flutter app which runs perfectly on the iOS and Android Simulator:
[app on iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaSyL.png)

But when I am running the same exact app on my iPhone 12, everything (fontsize, textfields, etc...) appear bigger and I therefore get a render-overflow error. This upscaling happens on every screen in my app.
[app on real iPhone 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yv2T.png)

I tried turning my mac completely off and on again.
Flutter doctor is also completely fine.

[EDIT] This also happens with the complete default Flutter project. I don't understand why the scaling only happens on the real device and not in the simulator.

Here is the default project in the simulator:
[image: default Project in Simulator]

Here is the default project on a real iPhone 12:
[image: default Project on real iPhone]

Comment: Please share code for better understanding of your problem statement

Comment: Happens also with the default flutter project (see [EDIT] in the post)

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculate the size dynamic with the MediaQuery.of(context).size
or use some kind of package , they do it for you dynamically.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';


void main() async {
    // Add this line
      await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
      runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     // Add this Widget and call your root Widget here.
      return ScreenUtilInit(
         builder: (context , child) {
            return MaterialApp(
               debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
               title: 'First Method',
               home: Column(
                   children:<Wigdet>[
                      Container(
                         width: 50.w,
                        height:200.h
                      ),
                       Text("Ola".sp)
                ]
              ),
        );
      }
    );
  },
);
```

}
}

Comment: I used the screenutil package like you described, added "designSize: const Size(360, 640)" in ScreenUtilInit and set the textscaling-factor to 1 with MediaQuery. As of now it seems that now the simulator and real device are the same. Thank you!